# Calculate Average transaction per second of aws lambda using cloudwatch metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, tps

How to derive the average tps of a lambda using cloudwatch invocation metrics ?

For a period of 12 hours , there were more than 10000 invocations happened. But when I change statistics to average /minute , the value is 1 .  When I change to average/sec the value is 0 .

Can someone explain how this works.